# Haskell "exceptions"

Tags: haskell, exception

I've got a set of users, groups, and a mapping between users and groups. I have various functions that manipulate these sets, however one should not be able to add a user<->group mapping for a user that does not exist, nor remove a group which still has users as members, etc.

So basically I want these functions to throw "exceptions" that must be explicitly dealt with by the caller.

I first thought of returning something like this:

```
data Return r e = Success r | Exception e
```

And if the caller fails to pattern match against the `Exception`, they'll hopefully get a compiler warning, or at the very least have an obvious runtime error when there is a problem.

Is this the best approach, and is there a pre-packaged solution that does this? Note I need to throw and catch "exceptions" in pure code, not the IO Monad.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, this is a good approach, and it's in the standard library: `Return r e` is the same as `Either e r`. You can even write code like you would using exceptions in `IO`, too (i.e. without having to explicitly handle the errors at each step with pattern matching): the `Monad` instance for `Either` propagates the errors, just like the `Maybe` monad does (but with the additional `e` value in the case of an error). For example:

```
data MyError
    = Oops String
    | VeryBadError Int Int

mightFail :: T -> Either MyError Int
mightFail a = ...

foo :: T -> T -> Int -> Either MyError Int
foo a b c = do
    x <- mightFail a
    y <- mightFail b
    if x == y
        then throwError (VeryBadError x y)
        else return (x + y + c)
```

If `mightFail a` or `mightFail b` returns `Left someError`, then `foo a b c` will, too; the errors are automatically propagated. (Here, `throwError` is just a nice way of writing `Left`, using the functions from [`Control.Monad.Error`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Error.html); there's also `catchError` to catch these exceptions.)

Answer (score 11):

The `Return r e` type that you are describing is exactly the standard type

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
```

You might want to use the so called ["error monad"](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/2.1.1/doc/html/Control-Monad-Error.html) (a more suitable name is "exception monad") of the mtl package. (Alternatively, there's `ExceptionT` in the monadLib package if you don't want to use mtl.) This allows you to do error handling in pure code by invoking `throwError` and `catchError`.
[Here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/All_About_Monads#Example_3) you can find an example that shows how to use it.